# Turning a sublist of a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I was wondering whether it's possible to get a sublist of a list into a dictionary.

For example, a list contains:

```
 cy = [["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["c", "b", "a", "c"], ["d, "b", "a", "d"]]
```

would be stored into a dictionary according to the first letter of the sublist

```
 {a : ["a", "b", "a"], c : ["c", "b", "a", "c"], d: ["d, "b", "a", "d"] }
```

Notice that it only stores the first sublist of the key that starts with the "a" and not the next.

My code is as follows:

```
def syn(graph,start): 
     empty = []

     cy = [["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["c", "b", "a", "c"], ["d, "b", "a", "d"]]

     lei = dict()
     for items in cy:
        if items[0] in lei:
            lei[items[0]] += items

        else:
             lei[items[0]] = items
        return lei
```

But all I get is

```
  {a : ["a", "b", "a"]}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can very cleverly iterate backwards, as @juanpa.arrivillaga's and @RomanPerekhrest solutions demonstrate, another approach is to simple iterate over the list and user the `any` function:

```
cy = [["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["c", "b", "a", "c"], ["d", "b", "a", "d"]]
new_list = []
for i in cy:
   if not any(i[0] == b[0] for b in new_list):
       new_list.append(i)

final_dict = {i[0]:i for i in new_list}
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'c': ['c', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'd': ['d', 'b', 'a', 'd']}
```

Answer (score 2):

With simple `dict` comprehension:

```
cy = [["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["c", "b", "a", "c"], ["d", "b", "a", "d"]]
result = {l[0]: l[:] for l in cy[::-1]}

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'c': ['c', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'd': ['d', 'b', 'a', 'd']}
```

---

- `cy[::-1]` - processing the input list in reversed order to prevent overlapping by same *next* "keys"

Comment: Nice! IMHO the list copying with `l[:]` deserves a small note.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to iterate over your list *backwards*, adding the list to the `dict` based on the first element. Since you go backwards, this guarantees that the *first* sublist will be the list contained in your `dict`:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for sub in reversed(cy):
...     result[sub[0]] = sub
...
>>> result
{'d': ['d', 'b', 'a', 'd'], 'a': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'c': ['c', 'b', 'a', 'c']}
>>>
```

So, you would keep the *last* encountered value, but the last value of list in reverse order is the first value in forward order!

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cy = [["a", "b", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["c", "b", "a", "c"], ["d", "b", "a", "d"]]

# create a df
df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in cy],[i[0] for i in cy])

# export it in reverse order
df.iloc[::-1].T.to_dict(orient='rows')[0]
```

Returns:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'c': ['c', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 'd': ['d', 'b', 'a', 'd']}
```